# SQL Server 2014 Latest CU / Service Pack

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, service-pack

Where can you find the latest SQL Server 2014 Cumulative Update (CU) and/or Service Pack?

Note: I added this question and answered my own question to make this easier to find for others in the future.

At the time of this question, the first several pages of Google results (when searching for "SQL Server 2014 CU") only mention CU 1-4, with no mention of the latest CU 5.  http://lmgtfy.com/?q=sql+server+2014+cu

Comment: [I keep a list here](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/team-posts/latest-builds-sql-server-2014/), but there are many others. Did you search at all?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes I searched, and added an answer. I just did not find the Q/A on the stackexchange DBA site, so thought it might be helpful for others to have on here. I tried to note that on my original question, but may not have worded it correctly.

Comment: I thought that I had read on meta that it is perfectly acceptable to post and answer your own question for an issue that you had that may help others.  When I Google "sql server 2014 cu", the top results all point to CU 1-4, and none point to the SQL Server 2014 build versions page that linked to in my answer, so I considered this a helpful question that may help others (and myself in the future).

Comment: I think it's reasonable to assume a search query may be more like [`latest+sql+server+2014+CU`](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=latest+sql+server+2014+CU) in which case the third result gives the desired page.

Comment: @BateTech I wasn't suggesting it wasn't acceptable to do so. Don't assume that everyone commenting on the question has even looked at the answer, never mind gone out of their way to observe that the questioner and answerer are the same person.

Comment: I favor [sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/) as I walk into lots of unknown environments. Sadly, I know the RTM build numbers by heart as I see them far too often

Comment: @AaronBertrand I totally agree with not making that assumption. That's why I attempted to note that I was answering my own question within the text of the question, but I did not do a good job of making that clear when I initially posted the question, so thank you for pointing that out.  p.s. I enjoy reading your articles and many helpful/detailed answers you've added here and on stackoverflow, thanks!

Comment: And a possibly referenced [meta question](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/q/1181/2131)

Answer (score 2):

For the latest CU and builds (this article will also include service packs when released): 
[SQL Server 2014 build versions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2936603)

As of 2015-01-13, SQL Server 2014 is currently on CU5, which was released Dec. 17, 2014.
Service pack 1 has not yet been released.

Another similar article, specific to Service Packs: 
[How to obtain the latest service pack for SQL Server 2014](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2958069)

Answer (score 1):

Like @billinkc, I use [sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/) as my go-to list when I see a build I'm not familiar with, and to check before each update cycle.

Note that there's also build 12.00.2464 after CU5, "3024815 Large query compilation waits on RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE_QUERY_COMPILE in SQL Server 2014"

Comment: Thanks to both of you, that site is a great resource, and I like the fact that it includes all SQL Server versions and truly includes all builds, as where the official Microsoft "SQL Server 2014 build versions" does not.

Comment: It does not, in fact, truly include all builds - there have been the occasional (rare) build that was missed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/) and Microsoft pages mentioned earlier, I also like [sqlserverupdates.com](http://sqlserverupdates.com/) created by Brent Ozar et al.