# Sql Server Service Pack Update Notifications

Tags: sql-server

Is there any option in Sql Server to enable notifications from Microsoft in a way that it sends us emails every time a new service pack is released?

I have multiple servers with different versions of Sql Server installed and I want the sql server to send me an email every time a new service pack is available

I read this article and it says there is no such option.

[Sql Server Service Pack Updates Article I found online](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/how-to-find-out-about-the-latest-sql-server-service-packs-and-cumulative-updates/)

But I would like to ask the question anyways in case if it changed during the latest releases.

Comment: you can signup for notifications at [http://sqlserverupdates.com/](http://sqlserverupdates.com/)

Comment: I have multiple servers with different versions of sql server and I want the sql server to send me an email every time a new service pack is available.

Comment: You can get alerted if you put either [Microsoft SQL Release Services Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/)  or [Microsoft SQL Server Version List](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/) on [watchThatPage.com](http://www.watchthatpage.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, there is not an automated way to have SQL Server notify you, but there are several good resources for checking in [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89164/sql-server-2014-latest-cu-service-pack?rq=1), such as [sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 4):

You could subscribe to the RSS feed on Brent Ozar's new site [sqlserverupdates.com](http://sqlserverupdates.com/)

He keeps an up to date list of the latest Service Packs and Cumulative Updates required for each version of SQL Server since 2005.

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is a way to automate being notified of an update for SQL Server, there are two actually.

1. Windows Server Update Services

If you are using WSUS in your environment you can setup an email notification report. I am not sure how granular you can get with this report but expect there is some way of setting up a report for only your SQL Server environment. It has been a long time since I touched WSUS, but do recall there was a way to group servers. If you could do the report for just your group of SQL Servers this would provide a nice notification for all of your database environment.

**EDIT**

Looking at this a bit more I came across [this SF answer](https://serverfault.com/a/645695/47078) that shows a PowerShell script you can run from your WSUS server in your environment to check for updates. You can just set this up to check for your database servers, then have it email you if one fails your check or has an update not installed for SQL Server. Although I would think going the report route would be easier to manage.

2. PowerShell

<strike>As long as your OS is running PowerShell version 2.0 or greater and you are OK with allowing Internet access on your server; you can can write a PowerShell script that actually hits [SQLServerBuilds](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/) site to return the current build or "SP" for your instance. If it does not match then you send out an email to yourself, or your team. This would require wherever the script is executed from to have Internet access, so may not be the idea method. Although you could run this from a dev or server that is allowed to have Internet access. You would just need SQL Server SMO installed, or could write the script to utilize .NET methods for connection to an instance.</strike>

Looking at this a bit more it is not as easy as it looks.